# neo4j replacement query for getting graph features

Tags: neo4j

I have following variables in my dataset: Customer, Merchant, Age, gender, category, amount, fraud

I need to generate following neo4j features from it:

Degree, Pagerank, Community for merchant and customer as well. So, eventually something like this:

merchdegree, custDegree, CustPagerank, merchPageRank, merchCommunity, custCommunity

// Computing PageRank for placeholder nodes (This won’t work because this library has been deprecated)

CALL algo.pageRank('Placeholder', 'PAYS', {writeProperty: 'pagerank'})

// Community detection using label propagation

CALL algo.beta.labelPropagation('Placeholder', 'PAYS', {write:true, writeProperty: "community", weightProperty: "cnt"})

// Viewing the PageRank results (WIP)

#MATCH (p:Placeholder) RETURN p.id AS id, p.pagerank as pagerank ORDER BY pagerank DESC

However, this library has been deprecated. I would appreciate if someone can guide me how to get this features and what is the alternate code or library that need to be used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Neo4j, the Graph Algo library was deprecated in favor of [Graph Data Science library](https://neo4j.com/graph-data-science-library/)

[PageRank is now here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/page-rank/)

Note: Some of the functions have may have evolved a little in the move, since I have it handy, here is an example using [Weakly Connected Components](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/wcc/) to identify graph islands and label them with a group number.  I'm writing back the values because I do this step during graph construction (as opposed to creating a separate virtual graph in memory)

with graph library I was using

```
//assign group by algo.wcc, was unionFind
CALL algo.wcc(null, null, {
  write: true,
  writeProperty: 'group',
  consecutiveIds: true
})
YIELD nodes AS Nodes, setCount AS NbrOfComponents, writeProperty AS PropertyName;
```

now with GDS I'm using

```
call gds.wcc.write(
{
        nodeQuery: 'match (n) return id(n) as id',
    relationshipQuery:'MATCH (a)-->(b) RETURN id(a) as source, id(b) as target',
    writeProperty:'group',
    consecutiveIds:true
}
)
YIELD nodePropertiesWritten
return nodePropertiesWritten;
```